# jQuery UI Slider minimum value reversing itself?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I have some JS which works as expected when you want to calculate 0 - 100% however when I want to limit it to 50% - 75% and I change the 1st input is goes backwards to 38% then works upto 75% any ideas on what's happening here?

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    // Ok, now setup the slider for the application process
    $('.application-progress').slider(
    {
        range: "min",
        min: 50,
        max: 100,
        value: 50,
        animate: true,
        slide: function (event, ui) 
        {
            $("#progress").html(ui.value + "%");
        },
        disabled: true
    });

    $("#progress").html($(".application-progress").slider("value") + "%");

    $(".step-container input, .step-container select").change(function () 
    {
        $('.progress-container').removeClass('completed');
        var fields = $(".step-container input, .step-container select");
        var percentage = 75 * fields.filter(function () 
        {
            return $.trim(this.value) != "";
        }).length / fields.length;

        var roundedPercentage = Math.round(percentage);

        $(".application-progress").slider("value", roundedPercentage);
        $("#progress").html(roundedPercentage + "%");

        if (roundedPercentage == 100) 
        {
            $('.progress-container').addClass('completed');
        }
    });
});
```

Full code and working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VJr9A/):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about exactly what you want, but something like that seems to be better (changes commented in code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var minval = 50; //you'll need them later, so global var.
    var maxval = 75; //idem
    // Ok, now setup the slider for the application process
    $('.application-progress').slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: minval, //or a fixed value, as you want.
        animate: true,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#progress").html(ui.value + "%");
        },
        disabled: true
    });

    $("#progress").html($(".application-progress").slider("value") + "%");

    $(".step-container input, .step-container select").change(function() {
        $('.progress-container').removeClass('completed');
        var fields = $(".step-container input, .step-container select");
        var filled = fields.filter(function() {
            return $.trim(this.value) != "";
        }).length; //fileds "filled"

        var totalLength = fields.length; //all fields filled.
        var percentage = minval + ((maxval - minval) * filled / totalLength); //new calculation
        var roundedPercentage = Math.round(percentage);

        $(".application-progress").slider("value", roundedPercentage);
        $("#progress").html(roundedPercentage + "%");

        if (roundedPercentage == 100) { //roundedPercentage = max, not 100
            $('.progress-container').addClass('completed');
        }
    });
});
```

[SqlFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VJr9A/12/)

Comment: That works a treat, however it says 50% when you load the page but the bar is set to 0 and not 50% what can i change to set  the slider value? thanks again!

Comment: also when the bar gets to 75% is actually appears full like 100%, any way to kept the filled bar at 75% rather to looking like its 100% filled?

Comment: @JamesBrandon never used a slider in my life. Could you put an sqlfiddle with this js code, but showing a bar (it's probably a css missing, but... it would be easier to test)

Comment: ok i have updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VJr9A/10/ if you see it fills up from 0 - 100 rather than the fill starting at 50 and upto 75? thanks again for your time

Comment: @JamesBrandon ok edited answer : it was just an error in the ` $('.application-progress').slider` declaration : min and max have to be 0 and 100, not related to minValue and maxValue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your values are not as you expecting them to be

```
    var fields = $(".step-container input, .step-container select");
            var percentage = 75 * fields.filter(function () {
                return $.trim(this.value) != "";
    }).length / fields.length;
```

The `fields.length` is 6 because you have 6 inputs.

The `fields.filter(function () {
                    return $.trim(this.value) != "";
        }).length` returns at first value of 3 because you have already 2 values in your buttons witch are couted as well.

That gives you `3 / 6 = 0,5 * 75 = 37,5` makes the value `38`

Im not shure what you want to accomplish, but changing your input buttons to `<button>` tags, or removing them from selector may help you.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLBYn/) without buttons and with debug alerts.